# Can I detect if user has touched anywhere except from Annotation, on the map?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkannotation

I am building an app and I would like to know when user has touched an annotation or anywhere else on the map. I have a button that I would like to display only if an Annotation has been selected. So, if user after annotation try to touch anywhere on the map (if is not another annotation) then make button invisible.

At the moment, I have tried the touchesEnded method but the problem is that it does not recognises annotations and land.

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if([touches isMemberOfClass:[BuildingViewController class]])
        printf("Building");
    else
        printf("Land!");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`touches` is object with class `NSSet`, so you can get object from `NSSet` and check it`s class membership. For example:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
```

You can get UIView from touch

```
UIView *touchedView = touch.view;
```

Then check this UIView class and compare it with yours

```
[touchedView isMemberOfClass:[BuildingView class]]
```

Also I advice you to check all touches in that NSSet.

```
BOOL isBuilding = NO;

for(UITouch *touch in touches){
    if([touch.view isMemberOfClass:[BuildingView class]]){
        isBuilding = YES;
        break;
    }
}

if(isBuilding){
    printf("Building");
}else{
    printf("Land!");
}
```

Comment: Hello Denis. Thanks for your interest. I have applied your advice but still facing the same problem. Touching on annotation but printing out Land! I can confirm that annotation is touched because inside didSelectAnnotationView method I have the button's activation and it's working properly. I have tried isKindOfClass as well but still ... :(

Comment: Ok, can you add line    NSLog(@"%@",[BuildingView class])    after  for(UITouch *touch in touches){  and copy here what printing out?

Comment: OK. You will think that I am kidding you but here is what's printing out: 2012-11-15 13:02:01.811 CoL[849:c07] BuildingView
Land!

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Please change NSLog(@"%@",[BuildingView class]) to NSLog(@"%@",[touch.view class]); and copy what`s printing out

Comment: No worries! I was wondering how will print different classes the previous line, but Obj-C always surprises me :) . I can see the error from here. Now, it is printing out, 2012-11-15 13:30:41.037 CoL[1047:c07] MKPinAnnotationView
Land! ... Need to re-define my custom BuildingView class or change the 'isMemberOf[]' statement?

Comment: Yes, you can change BuildingVIew to MKPinAnnotationView. Or try to get coordinates from UITouch using - (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view and compare them with your button coordinates. It will be more accurate. And also, check in this method that button is visible when touch coordinates is in it

Comment: I can say that latest post confused me. how locationinview is working, and from where I will get the coordinates of the button? By button you mean building's annotation pin?

Comment: Yes, by button I mean building's annotation pin. So you can try both methods. 1. check class name; and 2. check using coordinates; :)